# Changing the UserInput of a URL not working with multiple menus

Tags: javascript

I have a user input form with multiple drop downs that display based on user selection. When a user selects an option from the 2nd drop down I would like to append that selection to a url.

Here's what I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/142/

Here's the JS in question:

```
function changeText2(){
   var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
   var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
   lnk.href = "http://google.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(userInput);
   lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
```

The issue is once the link is set it will not change again if a different option is selected from the first drop down menu.

Repro:

1) Select List of Colors

2) Select a color  -- Link will change

Without refreshing...

1) Select "List of Numbers" from drop down

2) Select a number -- Link does not change

How do I get the link to change if the user decides to select a new option from the first menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique but you're using the same one twice - that's a no-no. Use a class for it instead. You should also get rid of those HTML binds with `javascript:`.

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/143/).

Comment: appreciate the reply and insight.